# Is my pymodbus slave code usable or have i done something wrong?

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

The code is the following. I apologise in advance if ive done something silly. I have imported time as i want to have a delay in my final code

```
from pymodbus.version import version
from pymodbus.server.sync import StartSerialServer

from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock, ModbusSparseDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext

from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer, ModbusBinaryFramer
import time
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import logging

from twisted.names import client

FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s'
          ' %(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def run_server():

    store = ModbusSlaveContext(
        di=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17] * 100), #adresse, verdi( di = digital inputs)
        co=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17] * 100), #--_-- (Coils)
        hr=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17] * 100), #--_-- (Holding registers)
        ir=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17] * 100)) #--_-- (input registers)

    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
#Dette under mås til og måte være fast(slik jeg forstod det) ellers ville du bare få tomme strings

    identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
    identity.VendorName = 'Pymodbus'
    identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
    identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/'
    identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
    identity.ModelName = 'Pymodbus Server'
    identity.MajorMinorRevision = version.short()

    StartSerialServer(context,
                      framer=ModbusRtuFramer,
                      identity=identity,
                      port='COM1',
                      timeout=1,
                      baudrate=9600)

    #if client.connect():
    #    print("det funker bro, u good homie")


run_server()
```

As I have no access to a modbus master, it is very difficult for me to know if it will work or not. I will happily be guided.

What I want is the code to connect to a master/client trough RTU and send some messages if possible

Comment: Your code is pretty much identical to [this example](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/synchronous_server.html) so I'd expect it to work. Note that your code will not "connect to a master"; the master initiates the connection ([in fact](https://modbus.org/docs/Client-ServerPR-07-2020-final.docx.pdf) in the spec "master" has been replaced by the word "client" and "slave" is now "server"). You can test using a client written with PyModbus (or a [utility](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)) (two computers, null modem, or [emulator](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. i have found a modbus master program that might suit my need. but i cannot use the same port at the same time it seems(i get an error when that happens).Can do it have to use the utility to get around this or do i have to do something else?

Comment: ran the code and connected them to a modbus master simulator. I got this as response. this is correct right?

Comment: 2022-03-28 19:03:08,541 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :46       Client Connected [COM2:COM2]
2022-03-28 19:03:08,542 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :581      Started thread to serve client
2022-03-28 19:03:09,545 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :185      Getting Frame - 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa

Comment: 2022-03-28 19:03:09,545 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :137      Factory Request[ReadHoldingRegistersRequest: 3]
2022-03-28 19:03:09,545 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :107      Frame advanced, resetting header!!
2022-03-28 19:03:09,545 MainThread      DEBUG    context        :63       validate: fc-[3]

Comment: address-1: count-10
2022-03-28 19:03:09,545 MainThread      DEBUG    context        :77       getValues fc-[3] address-1: count-10
2022-03-28 19:03:09,545 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :144      send: [ReadHoldingRegistersResponse (10)]- b'01031400110011001100110011001100110011001100111677'

Comment: Please don't put code etc in the comments (its hard to read); edit the question instead. You cannot just point two applications at the same serial port and expect this to work; use the [emulator](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) if you don't have two ports (and a null modem cable). I cannot say whether your output is correct (it depends upon what you are doing); a basic test is to write to a register and then read it (you should get the updated value back). Note that I'm voting to close this because its currently not really a question so [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).